# What am I doing wrong in this question- Search in Rotated Sorted Array...?

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, binary-search

**Question:**

There is an integer array `nums` sorted in ascending order (with **distinct** values).

Prior to being passed to your function, `nums` is **possibly rotated** at an unknown pivot index `k (1 <= k < nums.length)` such that the resulting array is `[nums[k], nums[k+1], ..., nums[n-1], nums[0], nums[1], ..., nums[k-1]]` **(0-indexed)**. For example, `[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]` might be rotated at pivot index 3 and become `[4,5,6,7,0,1,2]`.

Given the array `nums` **after** the possible rotation and an integer target, return the index of target if it is in `nums`, or -1 if it is not in `nums`.

You must write an algorithm with `O(log n)` runtime complexity.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2], target = 0
Output: 4
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2], target = 3
Output: -1
```

**Example 3:**

```
Input: nums = [1], target = 0
Output: -1
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= nums.length <= 5000
-104 <= nums[i] <= 104
```

All values of `nums` are unique.
`nums` is an ascending array that is possibly rotated.

```
-104 <= target <= 104
```

**My Code:**

```
class Solution(object):
    def search(self, arr, x):
        l=0
        u=len(arr)-1
        m=0
    
        while(l<=u):
            m=(u+l)//2

            if(arr[m]==x):
                return m
            elif(arr[m]<x):
                l=m+1  
            else:
                u=m-1

        return -1
```

Comment: You are using a binary search, which is applicable to sorted array (like `[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]`. However, the input is not sorted, it's rotated. Thus a single binary search is not applicable. In fact, you can use binary search twice. The first time is to find out the "offset", and the second time to find out the actual index.

Comment: what will be the better solution for this problem in O(log n) ?

Comment: Two binary search, it's still O(log n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `binary-search` but you need to consider that the array of the problem is not sorted *(sorted but rotated)* and you need to find the sorted part of the array on the left or right of middle.

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, arr, x):
        
        l=0
        u=len(arr)-1
        m=0
        
        while l<=u :
            m = l+(u-l)//2 

            if arr[m] == x :
                return m
            
            elif arr[m] >= arr[l] :

                # sorted part is left-side of middle
                if x >= arr[l] and x < arr[m]: 
                    u = m-1
                
               # sorted part is right-side of middle
                else:                          
                    l = m+1
            else:

                # sorted part is right-side of middle
                if x <= arr[u] and x > arr[m]:
                    l = m+1                    
                
                # sorted part is left-side of middle
                else:
                    u = m-1                    
        return -1
```

Check:

```
>>> Solution().search([4,5,6,7,0,1,2], 0)
4

>>> Solution().search([4,5,6,7,0,1,2], 3)
-1

>>> Solution().search([1], 0)
-1
```

Answer (score -2):

Could you simply use the **index** command

```
nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2]
nums.index(5)
1

try: out = nums.index(200) 
except: out = -1
print(out)
-1
```

Comment: `index` has the time complexity of O(n).

Comment: 'index' is not a command but a method of 'list'.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int s =0;
        int e = nums.size()-1;

        while(s<=e){
            int mid = (s+e)>>1;
            if(nums[mid]==target) return mid;
            if(nums[s]<=nums[mid]){
               if(target>=nums[s] && nums[mid]>=target) e= mid-1;
               else s=mid+1;
            }
            else{

                if(target>=nums[mid]&&target<=nums[e]) s = mid+1;
                else e = mid-1;

            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: while this might Answer a similar Question, this 1) isn't in Python and 2) doesn't have any context or comments as to what it's doing!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).